# Why does SELECT FOR UPDATE works only within a transaction?

Tags: mysql, perl, transactions, locking, innodb

I think I am confused with the [SELECT FOR UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) construct.
Example:

```
mysql> select * from employees2;  
+-------+----------+--------+-----------+  
| EmpId | EmpName  | DeptId | EmpSalary |  
+-------+----------+--------+-----------+  
|     1 | John     |      1 |   5000.00 |  
|     2 | Albert   |      1 |   4500.00 |  
|     3 | Crain    |      2 |   6000.00 |  
|     4 | Micheal  |      2 |   5000.00 |  
|     5 | David    |   NULL |     34.00 |  
|     6 | Kelly    |   NULL |    457.00 |  
|     7 | Rudy     |      1 |    879.00 |  
|     8 | Smith    |      2 |   7878.00 |  
|     9 | Karsen   |      5 |    878.00 |  
|    10 | Stringer |      5 |    345.00 |  
|    11 | Cheryl   |   NULL |      NULL |  
+-------+----------+--------+-----------+  
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I do the following in a script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  
use strict;  
use warnings;  

use DBI;  

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:testdb','root','1234', {'RaiseError' => 1, 'AutoCommit' => 0}) or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";  
my $sql = "select * from employees2 where EmpId IN (2,10) for update";   
my  $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);  
$sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";  
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array) {  
   print "@row\n";  
}   
sleep(9000);  
$dbh->commit;
```

I also in parallel a console and connect to the database.
So I run the script *first* and then in another session I do:

```
mysql> select * from employees2 where EmpId IN (10) for update;
```

The second select blocks as it refers to the same row.
This blocks either I do:

```
mysql> set autocommit = 0; 
mysql> begin;   
mysql> select * from employees2 where EmpId IN (10) for update;   
mysql> commit;
```

or just

```
mysql> select * from employees2 where EmpId IN (10) for update;
```

So it blocks irrelevant if it is in a transaction or not.
Now if I change the script as:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:practice','root','') or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

I.e the script does **not** run within a transaction the second session does not block!
Why does it block **only** if the script runs within a transaction?

Comment: To answer your new question: `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` only locks rows until you commit the transaction in which it is executed. `autocommit` is enabled by default, so when you don't explicitly disable it, every SQL statement you execute forms a separate transaction (with InnoDB, that is). In other words, your first `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is executed and then immediately committed, releasing the locks.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:Ah yes of course!Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: My comment was slightly off...at least for MySQL 5.5, if you don't execute `SELECT FOR UPDATE` inside a transaction, no locking happens at all (as opposed to locking, committing immediately, and releasing the locks as I said in my comment).

Comment: By the way, did you figure out the issue you had initially posted, where you were seeing locks on rows not included in the `IN` clause?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:Yes.The reason was that the table did not have a primary key defined

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html):

> Locking of rows for update using `SELECT FOR UPDATE` only applies when autocommit is disabled (either by beginning transaction with `START TRANSACTION` or by setting autocommit to 0. If autocommit is enabled, the rows matching the specification are not locked.

In other words, if you don't execute your first `SELECT FOR UPDATE` inside a transaction, no rows are locked.

Comment: What about if instead it’s a single query but the for update is part of a subquery of an update query? In that case the query is only one and not in a transaction but I guess it should work because the commit is done only after the update statement. And it is the parent of the select subquery having the for update

Comment: @91DarioDev "it should work" - what is meant by this? if there's no transaction and autocommit is enabled, there's no lock because subquery commits right away after completion