# select "for update" with JDBC?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, select-for-update

I want to create a `for update` select statement in Java using JDBC, but not sure how it would be done.

If you are unfamiliar with for update you can read about it here
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE

For example, I have the following select statements

My select statement

```
select email from email_accounts where already_linked = false order by random() limit 1
```

My update statement

```
UPDATE email_accounts set already_linked = true, account_link_timestamp = now() where email = ?
```

How would this be done in Java using JDBC while using `for update`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You first add `for update` to your select (and your other columns you want to update), and then you update them. Also, as noted in the comments, make sure your `getConnection` returns a `Connection` without autocommit. And you need to set a `Statement` type for scrolling and `CONCUR_UPDATABLE`. Something like,

```
String[] colNames = { "email", "already_linked", "account_link_timestamp" };
String query = "select " + Stream.of(colNames).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
        + "from email_accounts where already_linked = false for update";
try (Connection conn = getConnection(); // Make sure conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, 
                ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {
    while (rs.next()) {
        // Get the current values, if you need them.
        String email = rs.getString(colNames[0]);
        boolean linked = rs.getBoolean(colNames[1]);
        Timestamp time = rs.getTimestamp(colNames[2]);
        // ...
        rs.updateBoolean(colNames[1], true);
        rs.updateTimestamp(colNames[2], //
                new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        rs.updateRow();
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is `conn.setAutoCommit = false` necessary for the `for update` locks to be effective, or does it not matter?

Comment: Also, doesn't the `createStatement` need to be called with `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` so `updateRow` will work?

Comment: @GordThompson Good catch, thanks. Yeah. It was dinner time, and I got a bit in a hurry.

Comment: `conn.setAutoCommit(false);` right above the while loop would be ok?

Comment: @Arya - That should be okay, but you'll also need to remember to `conn.commit()` the changes, too.

Comment: @GordThompson something is wrong, the sql query is correct and works when I execute it using psql, but I get the following error when I run it in Java "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No primary key found for table email_accounts." even though I do have a primary key for the table. Here is the link to the method I am using

https://pastebin.com/kcQvWJUx

Comment: You probably need to include the primary key column in the `SELECT` to make the result set updateable over JDBC, i.e. add it to `colNames`.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible use prepared statements with for update?

Comment: Excellent response. Worked for me on both MSSqlServer and Oracle. Thank you again.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Do you know how this would be done with Spring JDBC? no one seems to know how to do it with Spring JDBC https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350833/spring-jdbc-select-for-update

Comment: In the portion of your code where we are supposed to run the business logic for the update (ie: between `rs.getTimestamp()` and `rs.updateBoolean`) are we supposed to keep the logic as quick and simple as possible? I usually run into issues if I keep a connection open while executing other code. Is there a way to do the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` where I close the connection after the `SELECT` and open it before the `UPDATE`? Or does this not make sense?

Comment: I am not able to use this for a group of records all having status say =0, we always need to have Primary Key in the select for update statement, else update on ResultSet is throwing java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01446: cannot select ROWID from, or sample, a view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.  I am looking to use rs.updateXXX() where in the select query I can lock multiple records (say 100). Dont see a way around.

Comment: autocommit must be disabled in for it to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22849532/3957754

Comment: @JRichardsz *make sure your `getConnection` returns a `Connection` without autocommit*

Comment: this doesn't commit the update. I had to add `conn.commit();` at the end to make it work